# python printing clipped squares

Tags: python-3.x

the python code is printing this

```
___
____
____
____
_
```

instead of this

```
____
____
____
____
```

this is the code some of it doesn't do anything because it has been commented out so just ignore the associated variables

```
X = 0 #majic number 
L = 0 #lines
i = 0 #list intilising varble thing

x = 175 #cordinates are x and y
y = 0 #dont set x&y above 175
Del = x + 1
X = y*176
x = x+X
stuff = []
for L in range(0,7):
        for i in range(0,7):
                i + 1
                stuff.insert(i,"_")



        stuff.insert(i,"\n")
        i + 1
'''stuff.pop(Del)
stuff.insert(x,"q")'''
print(*stuff, sep='')
```

in the current settings it supposed to print a 8*8 board. i have fiddled around with the position of the i + 1 but it didn't seem to make a difference.
if someone knows how to get in a alternating pattern that would be great.
when i did that i just got abbbbaaa. i should of mentioned this early but the end goal is to create a game of chess in the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the increminting operator '+='. i + 1 means nothing in your code and wont have any effect if you removed it. It should be as follows:

```
for L in range(0,7):
        for i in range(0,7):
                i += 1
                stuff.insert(i,"_")



        stuff.insert(i,"\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

`for` works very differently in Python than it does in, say, C.
Also, in Python, you only very rarely need to use indices, especially since using iterators is more efficient.

I think you were trying to achieve this with your example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
x = 3
y = 2
stuff = []
for L in range(y):
    for i in range(x):
        stuff.append('_')
    stuff.append('\n')
# the list now looks like this:
# stuff = ['_', '_', '_', '\n', '_', '_', '_', '\n']
# It contains y*x strings, each length 1.
# This is something like "char **stuff" in C.
output = ''.join(stuff) # this creates '___\n___\n'
print(output)
```

Note that the variables `i` and `L` are actually never used, we are just using the number of items represented by each `range` to iterate over.

Or if you don't care about the strings being stored in a list and just want to print the rectangle:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
x = 3
y = 2
for L in range(y):
    print('_' * x) # by default, print appends '\n' to the end.
```

`'_' * x` just repeats the string `'_'` `x` times, creating another string, `'___'`